# How to perform PHP Cron job in BlueMix Cloud server?

Tags: php, cron, ibm-cloud

I want to run Cron job in BlueMix in my php web application and I not found directly any Cron concept in bluemix. So how can I perform my cron task?

In many tutorial they say workload scheduler service but this is in java and I don't understand this concept and no good tutorial about this.

Answer (score 0):

For scripts that need to be called on a schedule, invoke them over HTTP from a cron job using `curl` or `wget` from a Linux host, often the one hosting the LAMP stack itself.

However, that doesn't work on a PaaS like Bluemix because you don't have shell access to any underlying VM, so the alternative is to install a cron job elsewhere on a server under your control and script it to hit your Bluemix script on a schedule.

Comment: If I need linux host to run cron then where is power of bluemix, It is depended on another hosting.

Comment: Did you find this Workload Scheduler sample app in GitHub? The Workload Scheduler is intended to provide similar functions to Cron on the Bluemix platform.  https://github.com/WAdev0/HelloWorkloadSampleApp

Comment: I had ran across that solution I posted along the way at some point during a project I was doing that involved Bluemix. It was a long time ago and had that in my many notes, so details aren't that great. That Workload Scheduler seems so much more a better solution, I wish I had stumbled upon that before or during the project. Thanks @ralphearle